# Error: Cannot find module 'zeromq' - nodejs docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, zeromq

I want to subscribe to ZeroMQ server by nodejs in docker. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/app
RUN chmod -R 777 /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json .
EXPOSE 8080

RUN mkdir -p node_modules/.cache && chmod -R 777 node_modules/.cache
RUN npm install

COPY . .
CMD ["npm",""start"]
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  subscriber:
    build: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/app
```

And here is my nodejs script:

```
var zmq = require("zeromq");
var sock = zmq.socket("sub");

sock.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");
sock.subscribe("block");
console.log("Subscriber connected to port 5555");

sock.on("message", function(topic, message) {
  console.log(
    "received a message related to:",
     Buffer.from(topic).toString(),
     ", containing message:",
     Buffer.from(message).toString()
  );
});
```

Finally I run it by docker compose up --build and got the folloiwng error:

```
subsciber@1.0.0 start
> node subscriber.js
avsapp-subscriber-1  |
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'zeromq'
Require stack:
- /usr/app/subscriber.js
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/app/subscriber.js:2:13)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
 requireStack: [ '/usr/app/subscriber.js' ]
 }
```

How can I resolve it?
I also add following command,  but didn't work.

```
RUN npm install --save zeromq@5
```